# nodejs express session not passing variables

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

I have a problem of the session variables not being passed around. I believe they are not even store in MongoDb since db.sessions.find() is empty.
My modules are

```
  "express": "~4.12.2","express-session": "~1.11.1","mongoose": "*",  
  "passport": "~0.2.1", "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
  "passport-local-mongoose": "~1.0.0"
```

my app.js has

```
 app.use(cookieSession({
  keys: "myapp.sid",
  secret: env.get("SESSION_SECRET"),
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true, 
   cookie: { secure: true },
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    touchAfter: 24 * 3600 
                      })
 }));

function ensureSecure(req, res, next){
 if(req.secure){
   return next();
 };
 res.redirect('https://'+req.hostname+':' + 8000 + req.url);
};

app.all('*', ensureSecure); 
app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken();  
 res.locals.session = req.session;
 // flash doesnot get passed, maybe same problem
 res.locals.sessionFlash = req.session.sessionFlash;
 delete req.session.sessionFlash;                              
        next();
});
```

it comes all before my routes.
In the login route I have:

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
if (err) {  return next(err);}
if (!user) { ..do something}
 var theSchema = mongoose.model('OneSchema');    
 theSchema.findOne({'oneschema': req.body.dbschema}, function(err, oneschemas) {  // go back and fetch some data, 
  req.session.role = user.role;
 req.session.name = user.username;
      console.log("session : %j",req.session);  // OK full info 
    return res.redirect('/settings');
 });  // findone
  })(req, res, next);   // end passport line
 });  //end login route
```

Now the settings has:

```
router.get('/settings', function(req, res) {
 console.log("session : %j",req.session);  // BOUM!!!!!
 res.render('settings');
});
```

BOUM!!: session : {"passport":{}}

I have been searching since yesterday, reading everything around. I have tried all ideas. But I cannot make this work. 
I would appreciate very much pointers to directions that can help me find the solution.
Thanks

Comment: There's a lot of noice in your code snippets (passport). Have you tried cutting all the nonessential stuff for testing your session store?
And are you sure that you include your session cookie from "/login" when you call "/settings" from your client?

Comment: Thanks. i have been looking well at my code, and  I changed cookieSession to session: now it works. Not sure I understand why. But it works